# wcout не выводит символы кириллицы

Tags: c++, c++11

Для отображения кириллических символов *Unicode* я использовал тип `wchar_t` и метод `wcout`, но они по-просту не выводятся. Что необходимо сделать для их вывода в консоль?

Comment: `cout << "текст";`  `wcout<< L"текст"; ` либо: `char* text = "some text"; `  `TCHAR* Utext =L"пример текста"`;

Comment: консоль виндовая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
#include <locale>

int main()
{
   wcout.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));
   wcin.imbue(locale("rus_rus.866"));

   wstring name;

   wcout << L"Введите ваше имя: " << endl;
   wcin >> name;
   wcout << L"Привет " << name << L"!" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```